# Literature on the reconstruction of proto-Greek

Tags: indo-european, greek, reconstruction

I usually find scattered proto-Greek word reconstructions, but I never came across literature that focus on the reconstruction of that language. Do you know of any?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "focus on the reconstruction of Proto-Greek?" What do you expect to find?

Comment: @AlexB.

Specifically, Brill has released in the past various titles dealing with reconstructions of Proto-Albanian, Proto-Italic, Proto-Turkic, Proto-Anatolian etc. While their main purpose is not necessarely the reconstruction, it is included. So it doesn't need to be a book dedicated to proto-Greek, but some kind of source including reconstructions of the basic vocabulary.

Comment: [Beekes](https://www.amazon.com/Etymological-Dictionary-Leiden-Indo-European-English/dp/9004321861/ref=asc_df_9004321861/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312114660688&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3099425312427424760&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9021603&hvtargid=pla-453884040139&psc=1) has a truly ***outstanding*** introduction and details why hes is objecting to PG reconstructions.